# Async method not writing in file

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have the following method:

```
  void saveProfile() {
    new File("Profiles/${this.name}.txt")
     .create(recursive: true)
     .then((File file) async => await file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(this.toJson())));
  }
```

But sometimes it does write on file, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure you're waiting properly for the write to finish? You method returns a `void`, so it looks like you're not `awaiting` it.

Comment: I've edited the code. Even when awaiting, sometimes the file does not write. About the void, the idea is to simply save a file, without returning it to anywhere on the code.

Comment: Can you show entire class that contains the `saveProfile` method and the place it's called?

Comment: The await you added doesn't change anything. I meant return a `Future` and await it. Otherwise, you have no way of knowing when the save is complete. I'm also not sure if errors are visible if you don't do anything with the future.

Comment: Thanks, Ignacior, but hacker1024 already resolved my problem. Basically, i wasn't waiting properly. I changed the return type to Future and awaited it where i'm calling the method and the problem was solved. Thank's!!!